# find a value of a sibling node in xml file with ant xmltask

Tags: xml, xpath, ant, xmltask

I have the following xml block (a standard jboss web.xml file) :

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>checkInterval</param-name>
      <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>reloading</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    .
    .
    .
  </servlet>
</web-app>
```

i want to select `<param-value>` of `<init-param>` with `<param-name>=checkInterval` and copy it. there are multiple (different) `<init-params>` so i need to choose it dynamically.

I have tried the following:

```
<target name="default" description="description">       
        <xmltask source="web.xml" dest="web_edited.xml">
            <copy path='/web-app/servlet/init-param[param-name="checkInterval"]/param-value/text()' property='property1' />     
        </xmltask>
        <echo>${property1}</echo>

</target>
```

expected result is -1, but instead the property is undefined.
any idea ?

Comment: apparently the problem was that the document contained  multiple XML namespaces. that is in the definition: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app id="XMLTask Demo" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.4" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http:/java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_4.xsd"> 
   <display-name>Application Display Name</display-name> 
   <servlet> 
   .... ` so `<insert path="/web-app/display-name" xml="New Application Name"/> `becomes `<insert path="/:web-app/:display-name" xml="New Application Name"/> `

Comment: more information on this can be found here : http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/11/01/xml-manipulation-using-xmltask.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath works fine for me, so I suspect this is a problem with ant (sorry, don't know much about that).

I have one suggestion, though: Try knocking off the 'text()' bit from the end?  It's possible that it's typing -1 as a number.

Comment: you are right, xpath is okay, the problem was with the ant task indeed that did not handle the multiple namespaces.